# Torrent Not Downloading(Network Problem)

Tags: downloads, connection, bittorrent, router

for the last few weeks my torrents have refused to download showing the error: connection timed out to trackers. I recently(around the same time the torrents stopped downloading) changed my ssid and password to my wifi.

I have a laptop with windows 8.1 and ubuntu 16.04 and a desktop pc with arch linux all not downloading torrents and showing the same error("**Connection timed out**") so i'm guessing the problem is with my router. I've tried restoring my ssid and passwd back but still nothing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have u tried on ethernet cable ?? And also see if uPnP is allowed in ur router settings.

Comment: Hi @DeepSidhu1313 thanks for taking the time to reply. The pc with arch linux is connected by ethernet cable and dosen't download. I did not change any settings regarding upnp before it stopped downloading although i've checked and upnp is not enabled.Security wise is it ok to enable it?

Comment: Which country r u from ?? Bcz recently some isps and governments has blocked torrents. uPnP is a network service discovery protocol helps torrents to find computers behind NAT. Ask your isp if they have blocked torrents. Also try downloading some linux distro via torrent. That will help u determine if all the torrent traffic is blocked or there is some other problem.

Comment: I'm in Kenya and we have no laws regarding torrent downloads. I've also checked with my friends whom we share the same isp and they are torrenting just fine. I've enabled uPnP and still nothing. I've downloaded ubuntu 17.04 from ubuntu and says could not connect to tracker.

Comment: And apart from torrents, internet is working fine.

Comment: Yap. On all three Os's

Comment: Hi @DeepSidhu1313 I've noticed if i "test port" on my clients it says port closed even though i have enabled uPnP in my router settings. Could that be the problem?

Comment: After a whole day of frustrations i've been able to finally figure it out the problem was the router firewall was set to high this blocked all ports and all incoming connections. It only allowed connections from a predetermined list of ports by the firewall.                                                                       When i set the firewall setting to "off" it changed to No Ports Restricted  and torrents started downloading immediately.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your problem. I was about to say that. Apologies i was busy somewhere. :). Please add this as your answer with complete set of steps you followed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.I have posted the solution as my answer @DeepSidhu1313

Answer (score 0):

After a whole day of frustrations i've been able to finally figure it out, **the problem was the router firewall was set to high**(High chance i set it when i changed ssid and passwd  but i don't remember it) and **blocked all incoming connections**. It only allowed connections from a predetermined list of ports by the firewall.

When i **set the firewall setting to "off"** it changed to No Ports Restricted  and torrents started downloading immediately. I even disabled uPnP and removed port forwarding and it's still working.                                                                                The issue was with the router firewall. I hope this helps someone avoid the frustration i have had.